# How to get rid of 403 error when using selenium in python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

How do I get rid of a 403 error? The site I am trying to go on allows me to go on for ~30 seconds (although it varies) until I eventually get a 403 error. It was working before today. I would think if I was IP banned then I would not be able to get on the site at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to "get rid" of a 403 error.

That error means, simply, that the website doesn't want to talk to you.

Maybe you've made too many requests lately and the host thinks you're a spammer.

Maybe the host doesn't like your IP address.

No way to tell why exactly.  The host just chose to disallow you.